# How to separate the numbers from my input on an array on vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get the different numbers and separate them because each number means something in my array. So, I'm getting the value from my input, with the numbers separated by a " ", and trying to split them, so each number belongs to an array in a different position. But, every time that I want to display my array, all the numbers are on [0]. Here's my code:

```
input = document.getElementById('input');
button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', findPacientZero);

function findPacientZero(){

    var data = input.value;
    

    dadoscortados = data.split(" ")

    var dados = new Array;
    dados.push(dadoscortados);

    var n = dados[0];
    var c = dados[1];

    document.write(n)
    document.write(c)
}
```

So, when the page displays the 'n', all of the numbers are displayed, while 'c' is undefined. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the input looks like?

Comment: It's like "a b c d e f g". For example "5 2 3 4 1 2 5 3", where the first number means the number of patients, and the second number means the number of different ways to contaminate and stuff like that, so I need to really separate every number.

Comment: `data.split(" ")` already returns an array, so on the lines below, you are inserting that array in another Array. Hence, `dados[0]` is the array, and  `dados[1]` is undefined

Comment: `dados` isn't useful, but `dadoscortados` is already the array you seek.  `var n = dadoscortados[0]` etc

Comment: Oh, okay! I didn't know that .split() already creates an array. Now it works, thank you so much!

Comment: What did you think it did?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot push an array to another array below way

```
dados.push(dadoscortados);
```

use this way

```
dados.push(...dadoscortados)
```

Comment: You can also just do `dados = [...dadoscortados]`, there's no need to use `push()`